# Closure of a set is closed - proof verification

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I want to prove the following:

> Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. Let $A \subset X$ be a subset. Then $\mathrm{cl}A$ is closed.

Our definition is $\mathrm{cl}A = \{x \in X \mid \forall \text{ neighbourhood } N \text{ of } x, N \cap A \neq \varnothing\}$.

I'm not sure if my proof is correct and would appreciate a check of it:

> We want to show that $X \setminus \mathrm{cl}A$ is open. Let $x \in X \setminus \mathrm{cl}A$, i.e. $x \notin \mathrm{cl}A$. By definition, $\exists$ neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N \cap A = \varnothing$. Then $N \not\subset A \subset \mathrm{cl}A$, so $N \not\subset \mathrm{cl}A$. Hence, $N \subset X \setminus \mathrm{cl}A$.

The typical proof would be to show that $N \subset X \setminus \mathrm{cl}A$ by taking some $y$ in $N$ and then showing that $y \in X \setminus \mathrm{cl}A$, which would be easy to do - but I would like to know if my proof above is also correct.

Comment: Note: in general, $A \not\subset B \subset C$ does *not* imply $A \not\subset C$. (Think $A=(0,1)$, $B=(1,2)$, $C=[0,2]$).

Comment: You're absolutely correct - a valuable lesson learned. Something felt off and I should definitely have checked whether that actually held. Mind posting this as an answer since the proof is wrong?

Comment: I added a couple of additional comments which should be helpful (I didn't think the comment itself was worth an answer).

Comment: Thanks for those additional comments - I would normally have deleted the question but it's quite a grave mistake so prefer it being kept around for reference sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: in general, $A \not\subset B \subset C$ does *not* imply $A \not\subset C$. (Think $A=(0,1)$, $B=(1,2)$, $C=[0,2]$).

Moreover, not being a subset of a set does not imply being subset of the complement (think $\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)$ and $A$ and $B$ as above), so also your last conclusion is incorrect a priori.

The only thing you can conclude from knowing that there exists $N$ around $x$ such that $N \cap A=\varnothing$ is that $N \subset X \setminus A$.